# Parsing XML file with Python

Tags: python, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am trying to parse an XML file using Python3.x.  I want to return True if the tag is found and False otherwise.  I am trying to read in 1 line at a time and check - using recursion if it is not found, but I'm not sure what the most efficient way of accomplishing this would be.  What is the most efficient way of accomplishing this goal?
Here is my code:

```
class XmlFinder():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        self._tokens = []

    def find(self, tag):
        ''' Accepts tag to search for - Parse the file, return True if tag is found and False if not. '''
        self._tag = tag
        with open(self._filename, 'rt') as f:
            for line in f:
                line = line.strip()
                tokens = line.split()
                if self._tag == self._tokens:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
             XmlFinder.find(self, self._tag)

def main():
    x = XmlFinder("filename")
    tag = '<to/>'
    x.find(tag)
main()
```

I have never parsed an XML file before so this is completely new to me.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a library like [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

class XmlFinder():
    def __init__(self, filename):
        self._filename = filename
        with file(filename, "r") as file_h:
            self.soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(file_h.read())

    def find(self, tag):
        return True if self.soup.find(tag) else False

def main():
    x = XmlFinder("filename")
    tag = 'to'
    x.find(tag)
main()
```